# Which Log4j2 configuration is taken up if there is a log4j2.xml in src/main/resources and src/test/resources?

Tags: java, spring-boot, log4j2

I have a java spring boot application, that needs only the junit test logs to be of error level.

If I have a log4j2.xml(with root level as error) in src/test/resources in addition to log4j2.xml (with root level as info) in src/main/resources which log4j2 configuration is chosen when  main application goes up?

I checked the documentation for apache log4j2 but I couldn't find any references to which configuration is chosen in this case and would also like to know why?

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.1/manual/configuration.html

Comment: Also apologies for any errors as I am rookie at this ~ Thanks

Comment: If you run a test it will come from `src/test/resourcs` if you run the application normally `src/main/resources`.

Comment: It depends on the order of those folders in your classpath. That is why you should call the test configuration `log4j2-test.xml`, which is looked up before `log4j2.xml`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz but if log4j2-test has root level as error it will override the log4j2.xml with root level as info. But I want the main application to run with level as info and tests with level as error. Also is there a default classpath order or is it random?

Comment: I think I don't entirely understand what are you trying to achieve: when you are running tests you want the main code to have a different threshold level than the test code? That is hard to achieve (as they probably use the same package names). If you want to see only messages from your code (both main and test code), you can set the root log level to `ERROR` and the level of you own packages to `DEBUG`.